# Load File to Oracle TIMESTAMP(6) Format

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to load FLATFILE data to Oracle via Sqlloader, but I'm having trouble with a timestamp(6) field.

I have timestamp values in the below format:

> **Wed May 08 00:00:00 UTC 2013**

I need sqlloader code to load this time format in oracle.

My current sqlloader code is below

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'MYDIR/my_documents_data.dat'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE sample_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
"MYID" INTEGER EXTERNAL,
"NAME" CHAR(100),
"DOCUMENTTYPE" CHAR(250),
"DATEADDED" TIMESTAMP,
"DOCUMENTSIZE" INTEGER EXTERNAL
)
```

Please advise me which format should I apply for this column `"DATEADDED" TIMESTAMP`, which is actually a `timestamp(6)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Wed May 08 00:00:00 UTC 2013**

Given that sample, the proper format is probably:

```
DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212 for the detail of the various fields.

You have to load your data as a timestamp with timezone though, because I used `TZR` to map the `UTC` part of your data. Something like that:

```
...
"DATEADDED" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE "DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY"
...
```

---

If you really want a timestamp *without* timezone, use that format instead:

```
DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "UTC" YYYY
```

This will assume that all your timestamps are UTC and will silently discard that information.

```
...
"DATEADDED" TIMESTAMP "DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "UTC" YYYY"
...
```